# Zoom causes graph to go out of the plotting area bounds

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm having an issue with my graph. When I zoom, the line goes over the edge of the canvas area and over the x/y axis. I tried adding a clippath but that doesn't seem to work. If I inspect the DOM in the debugger I can see the clippath rectangle is position exactly where it needs to be.

```
//The canvasGroup is the area between the axis
var clipGroup = canvasGroup.append("clipPath")
                .attr("id", "canvasGroup-clipPath");

var clipRect = clipGroup.append("rect")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height);            

//Function that does the zooming
function doZoom() 
{   
    paths.forEach(function(path)
    {               
        path.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
    });

    gX.call(xAxis.scale(d3.event.transform.rescaleX(xScale)));
    gY.call(yAxis.scale(d3.event.transform.rescaleY(yScale)));
}   

var zoom = d3.zoom()
            .scaleExtent([1, 5])
            .translateExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
            .on("zoom", doZoom);

//Register the event listener             
canvasGroup.call(zoom);     

//now loop over the data sets and plot each one
//For brevity, I'm skipping the loop and only showing the call to create the line
var path = canvasGroup.append("path")
            .attr("clip-path", "url(#canvasGroup-clipPath)")    
            .attr("fill", "steelblue")                  
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("id", lineId + "-line")
            .style("stroke", lineColor)
            .style("stroke-width", 1)   
            .style("fill", "none");                     

paths.push(path);
path.attr("d", function(d) { return plotline(i)});
```

Here is how it looks. 
Before zoom: 
[image: Plot before zoom]
After zoom:[image: After zoom plot overlaps the Y axis]

Comment: How is your `clipPath` created?

Comment: Just `canvasGroup.append("clipPath").attr("id", "canvasGroup-clipPath")` . The canvasGroup is the area between the two axis and contains the clipPath an the data paths (the plots).

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: Already doing that in the line below. `var clipRect = clipGroup.append("rect")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height);  `

Comment: You need to move the code to add the clipath way before you reference it

Comment: Actually, I do create the clipPath before I create the plot lines, I just pasted it in the wrong place.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle or a code snippet to illustrate the problem? It would help us to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by setting the clipping path on the path representing your data. When applying the clipping path the browser needs to decide which coordinate system should be used for the contents of `<clipPath>` element. This is controlled by the [`clipPathUnits`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/clipPathUnits) attribute which defaults to `userSpaceOnUse`:

> **userSpaceOnUse**
>   The contents of the [`<clippath>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath) element represent values in the current user coordinate system in place at the time when the [`<clippath>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath) element is referenced (i.e., the user coordinate system for the element referencing the [`<clippath>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath) element via the [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/clip-path) attribute).

When transforming the path in your `doZoom()` function, you are actually establishing a new coordinate system for the path. And, apart from drawing the path itself, this coordinate system will be used to compute the position and dimension of the clipping path. Thus, by transforming the path according to the zoom behavior, you are applying the same transformation to the clipping path whereby moving it away from the desired position.

Although it is tempting to set the `clipPathUnits` attribute to its other valid value `objectBoundingBox`, this is most likely not what you want for this case as it further complicates matters. When setting this value the positions and lengths of the `<clipPath>`'s contents need to be specified as [*fractions*](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#ObjectBoundingBox) of the bounding box!

Knowing all this, there is a much easier solution to it! You just need to apply the `clip-path` to an element which will not be transformed during zooming ,e.g. a parent group. Given the incomplete code you provided, this might very well work by setting the clipping path to `canvasGroup`:

```
// Set the clipping path on the parent group.
canvasGroup.attr("clip-path", "url(#canvasGroup-clipPath)")    

// Append the path to the group as before.
var path = canvasGroup.append("path")
               .attr("fill", "steelblue")                  
               .attr("class", "line")
               // ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. Moving the clip-path attribute to a group that's not being transformed fixed the issue.